# git hook on windows triggers vbscript

Tags: git, vbscript

I'm trying to add pre-commit hook to my repository.
I would like the pre-commit to trigger `vbscript` I created that perform several tasks.

Unfortunately I could not find proper and clear documentation  explaining how exactly this is done.

My `pre-commit` hook is of type `sh` (`pre-commit.sh`) and its content

```
/C/Temp/Test.vbs
```

My script is (located in `C:\temp`):

```
WScript.Echo "This is Test"
```

The error I'm getting is

```
/C/Temp/Test.vbs: line 1: WScript.Echo: command not found
```

It there any tutorial explaining how this can be done?

By the way - I cannot replace the usage in `VBScript` due to other limitations.

Comment: Look at stackoverflow.com/q/12410164/603855 (first answer is depressing, but maybe the second (powershell) can help you. Or you could *try* to use `/c/fullpathto/cscript.exe "c:\temp\test.vbs"`

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Thank you - I'll give it a try and inform